# nginx serving all requests from s3 instead of selective requests

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-s3

I have configured my nginx to get data from s3 in case of 502 error thrown by php, but it is accessing data for all requests even when there is no 502 error.

Here is my configuration file,

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen          *:80;
    server_name     x.x.x.x;
    root            /data/www/public/;
#    access_log      /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wf_err.log;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://x.x.x.x;


    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        index       index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location @static{
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        rewrite ^ $request_uri;

        rewrite ^/assets/(.*)/(.*)\.css.* /assets/$1/$2.css break;
        rewrite ^/assets/(.*)/(.*)\.js.* /assets/$1/$2.js break;
        rewrite ^/assets/image.*/(.*)\.(.*).* /assets/image/$1.$2 break;
        rewrite ^/assets/fonts/(.*)\.(.*).* /assets/fonts/$1.$2 break;

        rewrite /story/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/.* /story/$1/$1_$2.html break;
        rewrite /story/([0-9]+)/.* /story/$1/$1_1.html break;
        proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_pass http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   php;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        error_page 502 504 503 @static;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
#        return 502;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files
      location ~ /\.ht {
         deny        all;
    }
}
```

I have used fastcgi_intercept_errors to catch errors sent by php.
Then, using error_page directive, I change the location to @static, where the requests are processed from s3.

But I can't understand why all requests are going to s3 even when there is no error.

Thanks.